# Problem deploying web.py script on IIS7 via PyISAPIe

Tags: iis-7, web.py, pyisapie

I have run into a problem while deploying a [web.py](http://webpy.org/) single-file API on IIS 7 via [PyISAPIe](http://www.google.com.pk/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CBYQFjAA&url=http://pyisapie.sourceforge.net/&ei=LZTLTYqpCcKDhQf1-oGpAg&usg=AFQjCNF055NId0-sZVSpAuIJVmCTXGd1Zw). I am going to talk about that today.

I have successfully been able to deploy several Django web applications on IIS 7 using PyISAPIe. The `Isapi.py` module that I used for the Django sites looks similar to this:

```
from django.core.handlers.wsgi import WSGIHandler as DjangoHandler
from Http.WSGI import RunWSGI
from Http import Env
import os
import sys
sys.path.append(r"C:\projects\myproject")
os.environ["DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE"] = "myproject.settings"
Base = "/"
Exclude = ["/media"]
Handler = DjangoHandler()

def Request():
  PathInfo = Env.PATH_INFO
  return RunWSGI(Handler, Base=Base)
```

However, not knowing how to tweak the above to use with my web.py script, I started with the `WSGI` example `Isapi.py` file. After additions, I have the following file:

```
from Http.WSGI import RunWSGI
from Http import Env
from md5 import md5
import imp
import os

import sys
sys.path.append(r"C:\projects\otherproject\")

SCRIPT_PATH = 'C:\projects\otherproject\device_api.py'
ScriptHandlers = {
     "/": r"C:\projects\otherproject\device_api.py",
}
def RunScript(Path):
  global ScriptHandlers
  try:
    return ScriptHandlers[Path]()
  except KeyError:
    Name = '__'+md5(Path).hexdigest().upper()
    ScriptHandlers[Path] = \
      imp.load_source(Name, Env.SCRIPT_TRANSLATED).Request
    return ScriptHandlers[Path]()

Apps = {
#  "/app/django/"  : lambda P: RunWSGI(DjangoHandler()),
#  "/app/trac/"    : lambda P: RunWSGI(TracHandler),
  "/" : lambda P: RunScript(P),
}

def Request():
  Name = Env.SCRIPT_NAME
  for App, Handler in Apps.items():
    if Name.startswith(App):
        return Handler(Name)
  raise Exception, "Handler not found."
```

I am sure that there is something that I am overlooking or plainly doing wrong. When I try to access the script on the browser, I get a 500 response from IIS with the following details:

```
Could not initialize interpreter

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\projects\pyisapie\Http\Isapi.py", line 29, in 
    from md5 import md5
  File "C:\Python26\Lib\md5.py", line 8, in 
    DeprecationWarning, 2)
  File "C:\Python26\Lib\warnings.py", line 29, in _show_warning
    file.write(formatwarning(message, category, filename, lineno, line))
Exception: Not currently processing a request
```

While I am still playing around with different tweaks and such, I am not exactly sure what I need to do to get it working. Any help in that direction will be really greatly appreciated.

Thank you for your time.

*PS: I have this script, `device_api.py`, deployed under Apache2 using `mod_wsgi`, so I am certain there is nothing wrong with the code inside the script.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After labouring for days, I finally found a solution. I wrote it down in detail. I am going to provide a link to my blog post where I have put it down. It's titled, "[Guide: Deploying web.py on IIS7 using PyISAPIe](http://ayaz.wordpress.com/2011/05/14/guide-deploying-web-py-on-iis7-using-pyisapie/)". I hope it helps someone facing similar issues.

Thank you.